# How to fix libresolv dependency when using native binding in xamarin ios?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.ios-binding

While building, I am getting errors which I believe are related to libresolv, kindly suggest what needs to be done to resolve this.
[image: Error screenshot for the reference]

I have already enabled smartlink=true, forceload = false for native frameworks.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/10884) which is helpful.

Comment: Thanks @AlexandarMay-MSFT, issue is resolved by keeping Native link  
-libresolv

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT
Can you suggest on this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73161990/how-to-declare-method-in-c-sharp-with-parameters-as-handler-and-map-that-to-obj